# Print directories in ascending order using scandir() in c

Tags: c

While using `scandir()` it uses `alphasort` to sort the list of directory content in reverse order. Now how to print directories in ascending order using `scandir()` in c.

`.` and `..` must be on top.

Here is the code:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/dir.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main(void)
{
   struct dirent **namelist;
   int n;

   n = scandir(".", &namelist,NULL,alphasort);
   if (n < 0)
      perror("scandir");
   else {
      while (n--) {
         printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
         free(namelist[n]);
      }
      free(namelist);
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `alphasort` it will sort the entries in ascending order.

In your code you have printed it in reverse order.

To print in ascending order you need to start from index `0`.

---

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/dir.h>
int main(void)
{
   struct dirent **namelist;
   int n;
   int i=0;
   n = scandir(".", &namelist,NULL,alphasort);
   if (n < 0)
      perror("scandir");
   else {
      while (i<n) {
         printf("%s\n", namelist[i]->d_name);
         free(namelist[i]);
         ++i;
      }
      free(namelist);
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but shouldn't it be `free(namelist[i - 1])` ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Thanks, I overlooked it!